# Unsupported operand types in drupal form

Tags: php, drupal

this is my form

```
function dreamcharts_step7_form(&$form, &$form_state) {
   $dream = &$form_state['dream_obj'];
   $form['weight'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => 'Weight',
   );




    $form['tall'] = array(

    '#title' => 'How tall are you?',
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#required' => 1,
    '#default_value' => $dream->tall,
    '#value' => array( 
      '0' => '58',
      '1' => '59',
      '2' => '60',
      '3' => '61',
      '4' => '62',
      '5' => '63',
      '6' => '64',
      '7' => '65',
      '8' => '66',
      '9' => '67',
      '10' => '68',
      '11' => '69',
      '12' => '70',
      '13' => '71',
      '14' => '72',
      '15' => '73',
      '16' => '74',
      '17' => '75',
      '18' => '76',

    ),
    '#options' => array(
      '0' => '4\' 10"',
      '1' => '4\' 11"',
      '2' => '5\' 0"',
      '3' => '5\' 1"',
      '4' => '5\' 2"',
      '5' => '5\' 3"',
      '6' => '5\' 4"',
      '7' => '5\' 5"',
      '8' => '5\' 6"',
      '9' => '5\' 7"',
      '10' => '5\' 8"',
      '11' => '5\' 9"',
      '12' => '5\' 10"',
      '13' => '5\' 11"',
      '14' => '6\' 0"',
      '15' => '6\' 1"',
      '16' => '6\' 2"',
      '17' => '6\' 3"',
      '18' => '6\' 4"',
    )
  );

   $form['tip'] = array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#prefix' => '<div id="hint">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#value' => 'The combination of your weight and height lets us know your Body Mass Index or BMI.',
   );   

  $form_state['no buttons'] = TRUE; 
}
```

this is where I calculate the form values

```
function dreamcharts_step7_form_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {


  $tall = $form_state['values']['tall'];
  $weight =  $form_state['values']['weight'];

  $form_state['dream_obj']->bmi = (($weight * 703) / ($tall * $height)); 

}
```

I am getting  Unsupported operand types with this line

```
  $form_state['dream_obj']->bmi = (($weight * 703) / ($tall * $height));
```

Comment: `var_dump` everything on that line.  Guessing one is an array or something, not a numeric type like you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The '#select' type does not support '#values'. The values are taken from the key in the options array.

eg.

```
$form['tall'] = array(

'#title' => 'How tall are you?',
'#type' => 'select',
'#required' => 1,
'#default_value' => $dream->tall,
'#options' => array(
  '58' => '4\' 10"',
  '59' => '4\' 11"',
  '60' => '5\' 0"',
  '61' => '5\' 1"',
  '62' => '5\' 2"',
  '63' => '5\' 3"',
  '64' => '5\' 4"',
  '65' => '5\' 5"',
  '66' => '5\' 6"',
  '67' => '5\' 7"',
  '68' => '5\' 8"',
  '69' => '5\' 9"',
  '70' => '5\' 10"',
  '71' => '5\' 11"',
  '72' => '6\' 0"',
  '73' => '6\' 1"',
  '74' => '6\' 2"',
  '75' => '6\' 3"',
  '76' => '6\' 4"',
)
);
```

Comment: I figured this out thought i deleted this question. this is exactly the right answer

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that 5'3" isn't the right form for an arithmetic operation. Try var_dumping it to see its actual form (I'm just guessing here, could it be an array?)

Convert it to an int or float value (es. using the metrical system. Why not translating the value in centimeters?) in order to use it as an operand.

Comment: I liked your idea about changing to the metric system better :P

Comment: Althoug automatically type-casting to string will work, I'm positive it won't yield to OP's expected results anyway. I don't think php will translate 5'3" to whatever it means in a more rational (polemic mode on) measure system. Give it centimeters, operations love centimeters.